# Redo not working in UndoManager in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, undo-redo, nsundomanager

I'm implementing an undo/redo feature in my code but for some reason my redo feature is not working heres my code for the text view:

```
  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if descBox.textColor == .lightGray {
        DescriptionCell.descPlaceholder = descBox.text
            let descText = descBox.text
            undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: {
            (targetSelf) in
            targetSelf.descBox.text = descText
            targetSelf.descBox.textColor = .lightGray
        })
        descBox.text = nil
        descBox.textColor = .black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if descBox.text.isEmpty {
        descBox.text = DescriptionCell.descPlaceholder
        descBox.textColor = .lightGray
    }
        let descText = descBox.text
        undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: {
            (targetSelf) in
            targetSelf.descBox.text = descText
        })
        }
```

I then had this for my ViewController toolbar:

```
@objc func Undo() {
 undoManager?.undo()
}

@objc func Redo() {
 undoManager?.redo()
}
```

And then in the viewDidLoad:

```
let undoKeyboard = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Image-2"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Undo))
    undoKeyboard.tintColor = .lightGray
let redoKeyboard = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Image-1"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Redo))
    redoKeyboard.tintColor = .green
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if descBox.text.isEmpty {
        descBox.text = DescriptionCell.descPlaceholder
        descBox.textColor = .lightGray
    }

    let descText = descBox.text // <== Incorrect; Text has been set
    undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { (targetSelf) in
        // Here it means to reset the text (which already set in textDidEnd), thus meaningless (unless you made changes somewhere else and want to reset to the set text, which I assume is not what you want to achieve here)
        targetSelf.descBox.text = descText
    })
}
```

What you wrote here is register the undo manager with a set text (`textViewDidEndEditing` means the field has changed, thus the `descBox.text` has updated).

I suggest you change it to `textViewDidBeginEditing(_:)` and register the undo manager there. Sample:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let descText = descBox.text
    undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { (targetSelf) in
        targetSelf.descBox.text = descText
        targetSelf.descBox.resignFirstResponder()
    })
}
```

There, when you press undo, it will set the previous text (before any changed) and resign first responder (a.k.a `endEditing()`)